# How to extract information from Json file.Json structure must be mapped through type and use AESON

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import           Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC
import           GHC.Generics
import           Data.Text

data MainWeatherInfo = MainWeatherInfo
    { mainInfo :: Main
    } deriving (Show,Generic)

data Main = Main
    { temp :: Double
    , pressure :: Int
    , humidity :: Int
    , temp_min :: Double
    , temp_max :: Double
    } deriving (Show,Generic)

instance FromJSON MainWeatherInfo
instance FromJSON Main

main :: IO ()
main = do
  jsonString <- B.readFile "/home/ashot/test.json"
  let result = decodeStrict $ jsonString :: Maybe MainWeatherInfo
  case result of
    Nothing      -> print "error"
    Just result  -> print result
```

And JSON file:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 44.51,
        "lat": 40.18
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 299.15,
        "pressure": 1008,
        "humidity": 34,
        "temp_min": 299.15,
        "temp_max": 299.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
        "wind": {
        "speed": 1.5,
        "deg": 190
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.195
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 8
    },
    "dt": 1528615800,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "message": 0.0036,
        "country": "AM",
        "sunrise": 1528594331,
        "sunset": 1528648255
    },
    "id": 616052,
    "name": "Yerevan",
    "cod": 200
}
```

I need Extract "main" info.And i have type MainWeatherInfo.This code is compiled.But during startup I get an this "error". How can I fix this and get normal information?

Comment: What does the error say? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50782031/edit) by including the error message.

Comment: @MarkSeemann CallStack (from HasCallStack):  error, called at app/Main.hs 14:1 (MainWeatherInfo type) The problem is the type

Comment: Could it be that in the Haskell you called the field "mainInfo" but in the JSON it is called "main"? More generally, I find using automatic derivation for serialization is more trouble than its worth: I always write out the full instance. That way if the data structure or the JSON ever change I can roll with the blow much more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **aeson** is looking for a field called **mainInfo** within the file but such a field doesn't exist.

Initially I thought we could resolve the problem by changing **mainInfo** in the type definition for **MainWeatherInfo** to **main**. That won't work because *a function with the same name exists already!*

**aeson** provides a way out of this and you can find the description in [this helpful tutorial](https://artyom.me/aeson) under the section **Generics: customising field names**.

Just to be more concrete, if you use the turorial's method you'll end up with a **Main.hs** that looks like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}

module Main where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString as L

data MainWeatherInfo = MainWeatherInfo
  { mainInfo :: Main
  } deriving ( Show
             , Generic
             )

instance ToJSON MainWeatherInfo where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = take 4 }

instance FromJSON MainWeatherInfo where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = take 4 }

data Main = Main
  { temp :: Double
  , pressure :: Int
  , humidity :: Int
  , temp_min :: Double
  , temp_max :: Double
  } deriving ( Show
             , Generic
             , ToJSON
             , FromJSON
             )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- L.readFile "notes/test.json"
  let result = (decodeStrict contents) :: Maybe MainWeatherInfo
  case result of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "error"
    Just v  -> putStrLn $ show v
```

I tried it out on my computer and it worked fine.

**UPDATE:** I've been extremely silly and assumed that the solution needs to be restricted to just one module. It would probably be *much* better to have a **Main.hs** that looks like:

```
module Main where

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString as L
import qualified Weather as W

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- L.readFile "notes/test.json"
  let result = (decodeStrict contents) :: Maybe W.MainWeatherInfo
  case result of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "error"
    Just v  -> putStrLn $ show v
```

and also another module **Weather.hs** that is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}

module Weather where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types

data MainWeatherInfo = MainWeatherInfo
  { main :: Main
  } deriving ( Show
             , Generic
             , ToJSON
             , FromJSON
             )

data Main = Main
  { temp :: Double
  , pressure :: Int
  , humidity :: Int
  , temp_min :: Double
  , temp_max :: Double
  } deriving ( Show
             , Generic
             , ToJSON
             , FromJSON
             )
```

I tested it just to be sure, and it works.